# Windows 2008 Server Standard with a 5 CAL pack - do CALS expire

Tags: licensing, cal, oem

Bought Windows server 2008 Standard R2 which came with a 5 CAL pack, the server has since died and been hit with a hammer.
AS the OEM server license died with the hardware, what does that mean for the CALs, have they expired as well or can i continue to count them as my overall CAL figure?

Comment: It appears my question is more specific than first realised. No wonder its hard to find any conclusive information.

Answer (score 1):

RDS User CAL's (Assuming its per user CAL's) expire after about 60 days of not being used which means they go back into your 'unused CAL pool'.

Device CAL's are about 90 days if memory serves me correct.

However, this is only the case if you are licensing the machine against a licensing server. If no license server has knowledge of your 5 CAL pack then they belong to the license that has died with your server. I am not sure if you are able to reclaim those CAL's on something else.